# Is anyone able to fix the SBT Debian repository?

Tags: debian, sbt

The Debian repository at https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian has a Release file with no date. Debian has recently tightened up security of apt-get and aptitude so the Release file on this site is no longer deemed well-formed leading to the site not being useful. Can someone recreate the site so as to have an InRelease file that works?